# Binding @RequestBody, @RequestParam, @PathVariable to a single object

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

By Default Spring Controller will automatically bind @RequestVariable to an existing object if it can.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/...")
public ResponseEntity<?> doSomething(
    @RequestParam String filter,
    @RequestBody MyBody myBody,
    MyObject myObject)
```

If `myObject` has a String field called `filter` it will bind the `@RequestParam` to it. Is there a way to also bind `myBody` to it if it has a `private MyBody myBody` field?

```
class MyObject {
  private MyBody myBody
}
```

Comment: No there isn't, and it is also a bad idea. A controller is a singleton what would happen if you have 100 requests for that controller/object? Also there is no `@RequestVariable` there is `@RequestParam` however`.

Comment: Ah, good point- I mean @PathParam.  I still don't understand why this would be an issue given it is already working with @RequestParam?

Comment: Sorry, that is @PathVariable

Comment: It doesn't work for a `@RequestParam`... It won't bind to instance variables regardless. Also all those things are quite different, one uses binding of variables, the other is about unmarshalling body content. Different things which you generally don't want to combine.

Comment: myObject is a parameter not an instance variable.  And it does work because I tried it.  All RequestParam and PathVariables get mapped to their equivalent name on an object that it not annotated and a parameter to the method.

Comment: Yes then it works but in your post you said `private MyBody myBody` which is an instance variable and not a method argument. It works for method arguments but only when binding NOT when using `@RequestBody` as binding and processing the body are different things.

Comment: Oh yeah, that is confusing ... that  variable is defined inside MyObject.